# Finding the graph of a sinusoidal function

Tags: functions

> The graph of a sinusoidal function has a maximum point at $(0,8)$ and a minimum point of $(5,2)$.
>
> **Write the formula, where $x$ is in radians.**

I don't know where to start, and how to do the problem. Don't we have two possible choices:\begin{align*} & y=a\cos (bx)+c\\ & y=a\sin (bx)+c\end{align*}And I'm not sure which one to use. Since it seems like that *both* could work.

I know that the midline is $y=5$ so $c=5$ and this function has an ampitude of $3$. But I'm not sure what next...

Comment: "**The** formula" is clearly a mistake...

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I didn't quite understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What Daniel means is that there isn't any one formula to describe what the problem wants. In fact there are infinitely many formulas. And since cosine is just the sine graph transitioned over, you can use either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your maximum occurs at $(0,8)$ and your minimum at $(5,2)$, you know you have an amplitude of 3, as you stated, a period of 10, and phase shift...well, that depends on which function you want to use, $\sin$ or $\cos$. I argue for simplicity...indicating that we should use $\cos$. Try out the function $y=3\cos(\pi x/5)+5$.

Comment: Why is the period of $10$?

Comment: Well, that assumes the maximum and minimum are as close as possible together. Of course, your period could be *much* smaller if those are just arbitrary max/min. The *main* problem with your question is lack of specificity. Whoever wrote it...you should make a complaint.

Comment: Khan academy...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

first note that you can use a $cos$ function or a $sin $ function because the two functions differ only by a phase, i.e. $\cos x= \sin(\pi/2 -x)$.

Sowe can write the function in the form $y=a\cos (\omega x+\varphi) +b$ (the other form $y=a \sin(\omega' x + \varphi')+b$ being equivalent ) and we have four unknowns parameters that we can found with the four conditions:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(0)=0\\
y'(5)=0\\
y(0)=8\\
y(5)=2
\end{cases}
$$